# How do I add tooltips to fullcalendar LWC component

Tags: javascript, salesforce, fullcalendar, addeventlistener, lwc

I made a custom Salesforce lightning web component using the Fullcalendar js library. Now I'm trying to add tooltips that render when I hover over a calendar event. I'm using this demo as an example:https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-tooltip-demo. I cannot get the tooltips to show. I think the problem is in my eventlistener in the connectedCallback. But I can't figure out what the problem is.

Bellow is the js script I'm using now.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement, api, track} from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import fullCalendar from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullCalendar";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import getEvents from "@salesforce/apex/calendarController.getEvents";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

//global variables
var query1;
var query2;

export default class FullCalendarComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  calendar;
  fullCalendarInitialized = false;
  
  @api query1;
  @api query2;
  @track calendarEvents = [] ;
  @track finalEvents = [] ;
  @track calendarLabel;

  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.addEventListener('fceventclick', this.handleEventClick.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.handlehoverEvent);
  }

  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.fullCalendarInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    this.fullCalendarInitialized = true;

    //set global vars
    query1=this.query1;
    query2=this.query2;


    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.js"),
      loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/core/main.css")
    ])
      .then(() => {
        //got to load core first, then plugins
        Promise.all([
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.js"),
          loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/daygrid/main.css"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.js"),
          loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/list/main.css"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.js"),
          loadStyle(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/timegrid/main.css"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/interaction/main.js"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment/main.js"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/moment-timezone/main.js"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/popper/min.js"),
          loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/packages/tooltip/min.js"),
        ]).then(() => {
          console.log("init");
          this.getTasks();
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error", error);
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error loading FullCalendar",
            //message: error.message,
            variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }

  getTasks(){
    getEvents()
        .then(result =>{
           console.log(JSON.parse(result));
           this.calendarEvents = JSON.parse(result) ;
            console.log('Object Returned');
            this.initializeCalendar();
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            console.log('error');
            this.error = error;
            this.outputResult = undefined;
        });
  };

  initializeCalendar() {
    console.log(this.calendarEvents.length);
    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.calendarEvents.length ; i++) {
      this.finalEvents.push({
        start : this.calendarEvents[i].startDate,
        end: this.calendarEvents[i].endDate,
        title : this.calendarEvents[i].Name,
        id:this.calendarEvents[i].recordId,
        backgroundColor:this.calendarEvents[i].color,
        borderColor:this.calendarEvents[i].color,
        allDay:this.calendarEvents[i].allDay,
        className:this.calendarEvents[i].className});
    }

    var calendarEl = this.template.querySelector(".calendar");
    this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: ["dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list","interaction","moment"],
      views: {
        listWeek: { buttonText: "list" },
        timeGridWeek: { buttonText: "week" },
        timeGridDay: { buttonText: "day" },
        dayGridMonth: { buttonText: "month" },
      },
      eventClick: info => {
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('fceventclick', { detail: info });
        console.log("eventClick",info);
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
      },
      eventRender: info => {
        const hoverEvent = new Event('DOMContentLoaded', { detail: info });
        this.dispatchEvent(hoverEvent);
      },
      eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: false,
        hour12:false
      },
      locale: 'nl',
      axisFormat: 'H(:mm)', //,'h(:mm)tt',
      timeFormat: {
          agenda: 'H(:mm)' //h:mm{ - h:mm}'
      },
      weekNumbers: true,
      weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
      weekends:false,
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events : this.finalEvents});
    this.calendar.render();
    this.calendarLabel = this.calendar.view.title;
  }

  handlehoverEvent(event){
    let info = event.detail;
      var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: info.event.title,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
    }

  handleEventClick(event) {
    let info = event.detail;
    console.log('Event: ' + info.event.title);
    console.log('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    console.log('View: ' + info.view.type);
    console.log(info);
    info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard__recordPage',
      attributes: {
          recordId: info.event.id,
          actionName: 'view',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem

Comment: `I think the problem is in my eventlistener in the connectedCallback`...what exactly makes you think that? What have you observed? A common problem with tooltips not showing is that people forget they need to also copy the custom CSS from that demo, before anything will show up.